# Storing JSX code for late rendering

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Been trying this for a week!  I want to store JSX in an array I build with a parser.  I want to do this

```
JSX.push(<Accordion
              uniqId={'addAsset'}
              {...this.props}
              singleOpen={true} >);
```

Is this possible?  Could I store it as a string and somehow interpret an array of strings later as JSX code?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, since you can only use JSX the return value of your component. Why don't you store the data you need instead and then map that data when you are rendering the component?

Comment: It is supposed to be a form creator.  I don't know the components until after I parse a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is not possible with `data`

```
JSX.push(<Accordion
              uniqId={'addAsset'}
              {...this.props}
              singleOpen={true} >);
```

You can store data in array and later you can map and call component using array data...

Other option is

You can store the component into an `array` without data and later you can call that component.

```
JSX.push(Accordion);
JSX.push(TextBox);
```

and then

```
JSX.map(function(item){
    <item {...data}/>
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give the second a try.